# devtools::install_github() - Ignore SSL cert verification failure

Tags: r, rcurl, devtools

I'm trying to get `devtools::install_github()` working behind my corporate proxy on Windows 7.

So far I've had to do the following:

```
> library(httr)
> library(devtools)
> set_config(use_proxy("123.123.123.123",8080))
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/ggvis")

Installing github repo ggvis/master from rstudio
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/archive/master.zip
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Apparently we have some kind of certificate server replacing SSL certs with our own corporate SSL certs (confirmed by going to https://github.com and examining the cert).

Anyhow, just wondering if there's a way to ignore that cert error and proceed with the installation?

Comment: It might not be the nicest solution but would downloading the zip from the github repo and installing locally be an acceptable solution if all else fails?

Comment: Good idea - I hadn't even considered it. Still very much hoping not to have to do that though.

Comment: Try `set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) )`

Comment: It works. Thanks!! Do you want to turn that into an answer?

Comment: @jdharrison  could not find function "set_config"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One way to handle the problem is to set the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false. This option determines whether curl verifies the authenticity of the peer's certificate. A value of 1 means curl verifies; 0 (zero) means it doesn't.
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html

The relevant option needs to be passed to `RCurl`. In `RCurl` the `CURLOPT_` is removed letters arre lowercase and the underscore is changed to  `.`.

```
set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

will pass the relevant option to `RCurl` when using `httr`.

UPDATE:

The `httr` since this answer was written has moved from RCurl as an underlying dependence to the `curl` package. cURL options are now specified 
with underscores so the above would be:

```
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

in the current version of `httr`.

Comment: Had to change ssl.verifypeer -> ssl_verifypeer after upgrading Ubuntu and R.

Comment: @jdharrison could not find function "set_config"

Comment: You have to load the `httr` package before trying to use the set_config snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

I tired @jdharrisonbut method but it didn't worked for me.

A Quick fix to avoid using https connection, is by replacing https by http. you install a package from cran by this method.

install.packages("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggvis_0.4.4.tar.gz", repo=NULL, type="source")