# R negotiate authentication (with RCurl or Httr)

Tags: r, kerberos, rcurl, httr

I am trying to access a web service from R using RCurl. The web service uses Kerberos authentication.

Testing using curl on the command line works fine e.g.

```
curl --negotiate -u: http://reuxeuls199:8084/reports-ws/api/r/1.0/vesselTracking?region-name=ECC&start-date-time=01/10/2014
```

However in R I am unable to make it work.

```
ReportsProdURL <- "http://reuxeuls199:8084/reports-ws/api/r/1.0/vesselTracking?region-    name=ECC&start-date-time=01/10/2014"
URL <- getURL(ReportsProdURL, verbose=TRUE, .opts=curlOptions(username=":"))
```

I also tried using the `httpauth` option set to `gssnegotiate`, but that fails also.

Comment: What does the output from using the `verbose` option (that you're using) produce?

Comment: What happens on the console? How does it get your username and password?

Answer (score 3):

Using [httr](/questions/tagged/httr),

```
httr::GET(ReportsProdURL, 
    authenticate(":", "", type="gssnegotiate"))
```

And if no proxy is required for an internal website, then

```
httr::GET(ReportsProdURL, 
    use_proxy(""), 
    authenticate(":", "", type="gssnegotiate"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not found out how to do it with RCurl but with [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) you can use

```
GET("https://host.domain/",authenticate("username","password","gssnegotiate"))
```

In case you are using a self signed certificate you [can run the command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793863/devtoolsinstall-github-ignore-ssl-cert-verification-failure)

```
set_config( config( ssl.verifypeer = 0L ) )
```

To disable certificate validation for the underlying libcurl library

Answer (score 1):

With RCurl, for NEGOTIATE, use this:

```
getURL("https://yourAddress", userpwd=":", httpauth = 4)
```

The number 4 ist based on a bitmask of constants defined in [curl.h](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h). Valid options are defined [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.html).