# R - install_github fails

Tags: r, github, rcurl

I am trying to install a package from github in R, however I am getting the following error:

```
> install_github("jmp75/rClr", build_vignettes=TRUE)
Downloading github repo jmp75/rClr@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

I have set the RCurl options as such:

```
options(RCurlOptions = c(getOption("RCurlOptions"),   ssl.verifypeer = FALSE,  ssl.verifyhost = FALSE ) )
```

After checking the setting:

```
getOption("RCurlOptions")
```

we see....

```
$cainfo
[1] "C:/_CODE/R/Library/RCurl/etc/ca-bundle.crt"

$ssl.verifypeer
[1] FALSE

$ssl.verifyhost
[1] FALSE
```

Still I get the error:

```
Downloading github repo jmp75/rClr@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

any clues

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Does this work? I had to change this bit of code recently from `ssl.verifypeer` to `ssl_verifypeer`

```
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

see here [devtools::install_github() - Ignore SSL cert verification failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793863/devtoolsinstall-github-ignore-ssl-cert-verification-failure)

Comment: I don't think the `library(RCurl)` line is needed? For anyone else who runs into this problem often: I added a line to my .Rprofile file: `.fixdevtools <- function() { httr::set_config( httr::config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) ) }`

Now I just need to type `.fixdevtools()` every time instead of coming back to google and finding this answer :)