# unable to install gganimate package from Github, both automatically and manually

Tags: r, installation, manual

I am currently trying to install the gganimate package but seem unable to.
I am running Win 10, Rx64 3.3.0 and Rstudio 0.99.896;
the following command:

```
devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")
```

will throw this error:

```
Downloading GitHub repo dgrtwo/gganimate@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/dgrtwo/gganimate/zipball/master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

So after a few hours of despair, I decided to try and install the package manually. I followed this link:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806705/manually-downloading-and-installing-packages-in-r?lq=1)

the following command:

```
install.packages(pkgs = "C:/Users/Superzucca/Desktop/gganimate-master.zip", repos = NULL)
```

results in:

```
    Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Superzucca/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

but then when I call:

```
library("gganimate-master") ####  -> as suggsted by R itself!!
```

this error is thrown:

```
Error in library("gganimate-master") : there is no package called ‘gganimate-master’
```

please, help. I don't have any problems installing other pkgs and honestly don't know what else to try.
Thank you in advance,
Superzucca

Comment: After installing manually, `library(gganimate)` doesn't work?

Comment: it says there's no package called like that. I've tried adding and removing quotes, tried with "gganimate", "gganimate-master" as R suggests... nothing. It just won't load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem, updating with an answer if anybody in the future might need it.

this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293325/r-install-github-fails) to another SO question partially solved my problem; 
I also had to add R, Rstudio and the library folder to my AntiVirus' excption list, and of course running as administrator :)

Answer (score 4):

Try out this. It's working for me.

```
library(devtools)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the accepted answer and the other answer that is almost identical. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like you but I was successful at last.

Generally, you have to deal with two issues: first, connecting to github; second, installing both `Rcpp` and `gganimate`.

```
    library(devtools)
    library(RCurl)
    library(httr)
    set_config( config( ssl_verifypeer = 0L ) )
    devtools::install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
    devtools::install_github("dgrtwo/gganimate")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
install.packages("gganimate")
```

> **Note:** This will depend on the version of R installed and if you are downloading from the Cran site.

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer