# How to install install_github function on R?

Tags: r, github, installation, r-package

I am trying to use a github package from a worked example. I used the suggested methods

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293325/r-install-github-fails) to get the install-github working

```
library(devtools)
library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
install.packages("install_github")
install_github("ggbiplot", "vqv")
```

I get a warning that redirects me to the `R website` install page, and then error `Error in parse_repo_spec(repo) : Invalid git repo specification: 'ggbiplot'`

Ultimately, I want to run this piece of code

```
# Load data
data(iris)
log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
ir.species <- iris[, 5]

#PCA
ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir,
                 center = TRUE,
                 scale. = TRUE) 
#Plot
g <- ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
              groups = ir.species, ellipse = TRUE, 
              circle = TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = '')
g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
               legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `user/repo` syntax to specify the repo, since there are multiple packages called `ggbiplot` on GitHub - the R package has 157 forks and you have to tell R which one you want:

```r
library(devtools)

install_github('vqv/ggbiplot')
#> Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@HEAD

library(ggbiplot)
```

Now we can run your code:

```r
data(iris)
log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
ir.species <- iris[, 5]

#PCA
ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir,
                 center = TRUE,
                 scale. = TRUE) 
#Plot
g <- ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, 
              groups = ir.species, ellipse = TRUE, 
              circle = TRUE)
g <- g + scale_color_discrete(name = '')
g <- g + theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal', 
               legend.position = 'top')
print(g)
```

[image]