# How to pass ssl_verifypeer in Rvest?

Tags: r, ssl, curl, httr, rvest

I'm trying to use Rvest to scrape a table off of an internal webpage here at $JOB. 
I've used [the methods listed here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/) to get the xpath, etc.

My code is pretty simple:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
un = "username"; pw = "password"

thexpath <- "//*[@id="theFormOnThePage"]/fieldset/table"    

url1 <- "https://biglonghairyURL.do?blah=yadda"

stuff1 <- read_html(url1, authenticate(un, pw))
```

This gets me an error of: *"Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates."*

Leaving aside the not-up-to-datedness of the certificates, I've see that [it's possible using httr to avoid the ssl verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793863/devtoolsinstall-github-ignore-ssl-cert-verification-failure/24794044#24794044) using `set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))`.

This works just peachy if I use GET(url1) from httr, but the whole point is to automate scraping of the table using rvest.

Looking at the PDFs for [Rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf), and [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/httr.pdf), it seems that Rvest calls httr to pass on the curl commands, and that in httr, you can use `config()`.

So, to complete the syllogism, how can I (or is it even possible?) to pass the ssl_verifypeer = 0L directly through rvest::read_html?

I've tried a fair number of variations:

```
stuff1 <- read_html(url1, authenticate(un, pw), ssl_verifypeer = 0L)) 
stuff1 <- read_html(url1, authenticate(un, pw), config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))) 
stuff1 <- with_config(config = config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L), read_html(url1, authenticate(un, pw)))
```

And all of them throw the same error of *"Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates."*

Hopefully it's possible and I'm just not putting the correct syntax together?

Someone suggested using RSelenium, but since this is in a protected VM, getting java and/or new packages installed takes an act of Congress (along with a VP signoff) and would be my very last resort.

I very much appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: Why not `read_html(content(GET(…), as="text")` (provided the ssl verify peer thing works w/`GET`)? That's a legit way of passing in the HTML to `read_html` and still very scriptable.

Comment: hrbrmstr, that's the answer. If you'll set it up, I'll close this one out.