# bigrquery error as 'Unknown option: ssl.verifypeer' in query_exec function

Tags: r, google-bigquery, ubuntu-14.04

I get the following error after executing `query_exec` function in bigrquery:

> Waiting for authentication in browser... Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
>   Authentication complete. Error in curl::handle_setopt(handle, .list =
>   req$options) :    Unknown option: ssl.verifypeer

Attaching the R session info.

How can I identify and fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: Adding the missed out part of sessionInfo:                                              loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0   R6_2.2.1         assertthat_0.2.0 DBI_0.6-1       
[5] Rcpp_0.12.11     jsonlite_1.5     httpuv_1.3.5     openssl_0.9.6

Comment: Look here: [https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery](https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery). The first time you use bigrquery in a session, it will ask you to authorize bigrquery in the browser.

Comment: ^ Priyanka, if you have additional material for your question, please use the edit feature rather than the comments. Editing extra detail in to the question body helps keep all the useful information in one place.

Comment: @YCR The error appeared after authorizing bigrquery in the browser. There is no problem in authorization, the problem is after it. Thanks

Comment: try to confirm if you are using latest version of bigrquery and other related libraries

Answer (score 1):

In the recent versions of httr the option ssl.verifypeer has been changed to ssl_verifypeer. There was a similar kind of question asked in the following link:

[Ignore SSL cert verification failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24793863/devtoolsinstall-github-ignore-ssl-cert-verification-failure)